# gets in AVR microcontroller just reads two characters

Tags: c++, c, microcontroller, avr, gsm

I am doing a proyect that involves communication between a GSM module and a ATMEGA328P. I try to emulate through a terminal the GSM module before actually trying with the AVR to check if my program works correctly, however whenever I input a string that is read by a "gets" function, the string is not properly captured. I checked by trying to display it with a "printf" after reading it and it only displays the first two characters. Any idea why is this happening? I try to empty the buffer after typing the string with this: "while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n'); to avoid problems since I have to read multiple values and whenever I type I append CR+LF as the GSM module does to answer.

Here is the part of the code:

```
writeSerial("AT+CMGF=1");
clear();
readSerial(status);
writeSerial(status);
```

The functions listed above are declared as the following:

```
void clear(void){
    char ch;    
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n');
}

void readSerial(char *arr){
    gets(arr,sizeof(arr));
}

void writeSerial(char *arr){
    printf("%s\r\n", arr); //CR+LF
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` doesn't do what you think it does - it just gives you the size of the pointer itself, not the size of the buffer it points to. You'll need to pass an additional parameter for the buffer size.

Comment: Where is this `gets` function defined? There is, or rather was, a function by that name in the C standard library, but it only takes one argument. (It was removed in C11 because it cannot be used safely.) If possible, I suggest giving it a different name to avoid confusion for human readers and possibly for the compiler and/or linker.

Comment: You are expecting `sizeof` to accomplish magic.

Comment: The strange thing about the gets() is although in the AVR Libc Reference Manual it is shown with just one parameter, in CodeVision I receive the error message "to few arguments in function call" if I don't put the lenght of the array. Is my CodeVision Libc version maybe a bit old?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof(arr)` == 2 because arr is a `char*` not an array.

Arrays in C are not [first class data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) and cannot be passed to a function; instead a pointer is passed and the array size information is lost.  You need to pass the length separately.

```
void readSerial(char *arr, size_t len )
{
    gets( arr, len ) ;
}
```

Note that the standard library `gets()` does not take a size parameter in any case.  I am assuming this is a non-standard implementation.

As an aside, your `clear()` function can be simplified:

```
void clear(void)
{
    while( getchar() != '\n' ) ;
}
```

Though note that if the buffer is already empty, it will wait indefinitely for a new-line, so is probably not what you want in any case.

Comment: Cool! I guess what sizeof() is actually reading is the size of the pointer as said in other answers to this post. The strange thing about the gets() is although in the AVR Libc Reference Manual it is shown with just one parameter, in CodeVision I receive the error message "to few arguments in function call" if I don't put the lenght of the array. Anyway, now it works, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Consider rewriting your readSerial function as:

```
void readSerial(char *arr, size_t array_size ){
    gets(arr, array_size);
}
```

Function should be called like this:

```
char a[20] = {0};
readSerial( a, sizeof(a) );
```

In your case size of operator returns size of pointer to a char ( char * ) not the size of an array.

Comment: But still the sizeof(a) still just gives me the size of just the first element in the array, or am I wrong? Anyways the extra parameter solution works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: @ToñoM No, `sizeof(a)` gives you the number of bytes occupied by the whole array. `sizeof(a[0])` would give you the number of bytes occupied by the first element. `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` is a common idiom for getting the number of elements in an array, but since your array is of `char` and `sizeof(char)==1` (by definition) it's unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
void readSerial(char *arr) {
  gets(arr,sizeof(arr));
}
```

On your AVR pointers are 16-bits wide so `sizeof(arr) == 2`. Instead of using `sizeof`, perhaps pass in the byte length of `arr` as an additional parameter to `readSerial()`.